# Attach deferred handlers to nested AJAX call outside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I'm trying to create an AJAX method extension called getApi that will automatically add my bearer token to the request header.

I have a deferred function called `getToken()` that returns either the token from sessionStorage or from an endpoint if it has expired.

My extension method looks like this:

```
$.getApi = function (options) {
    getToken()
        .done(function (token) {
            options.headers = {
                Authorization: token
            };

            $.get(options);
        });
};
```

And I want to be able to attach a done() handler to the internal get request, like this:

```
$.getApi({
    url: "my endpoint" // Returns json
})
    .done(function (data) {
        // Do stuff with the json data
    });
```

How can I alter my getApi extension method to be able to attach handlers to the internal get request? Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: `return getToken().then(...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the promise interface (`then`). Also *return* `$.get()` so you extend the promise chain:

```
$.getApi = function (options) {
    return getToken().then(function (token) {
 // ^^^^^^            ^^^^  
        options.headers = {
            Authorization: token
        };
        return $.get(options);
 //     ^^^^^^
    });
};

$.getApi({
    url: "my endpoint"
}).then(function (data) {
// ^^^^
    // ...etc
});
```

NB: There is no good reason to define `getApi` on the `jQuery` object. I would advise to just make it a global function: `getApi`.

Comment: Thanks, it was the `then()` that I was missing instead of `done()`. Options is the ajax options that are passed into the getApi function.

Comment: Ah, yes, `options` is fine as it is.